# ユーザーが入力した文字をランダムで表示させたい

Tags: javascript

### 前提・実現したいこと

ユーザーが入力した文字をランダムで表示させたいです。
例えば「さかな」「にく」「ごはん」と入力させたら、「にくごはんさかな」「ごはんさかなにく」など、ランダムに順番が入れ替わるスクリプトを作りたいです。
もしも2つしか入力がなかった場合は、その2つだけでランダム表示させたいです。

### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

入力項目1つずつに変数を作るとすると、その変数をランダム表示させればいいんだと思うのですが、空欄がある時はその空欄を自動で無視して、空欄じゃない変数を表示させる方法がよく分かりません。そもそも、ランダムで変数の内容を表示させる方法も分からないです。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/298086

Comment: 「ユーザに３つ文字列を入力してもらう」というコードは作れますか? 「その文字列をJavaScriptの変数に入れる」は作れますか? できる範囲まででよいので、自分でコードを書いてみましょう。

Answer (score 0):

Like a comment said you need to get the input into variables somehow

For simplicity we can use `window.prompt`, then to select a random one we should store each variable in an area, then to display it were can just use document.body.innerHTML

So

```
<body>

<Script>
var things=[]
var one=prompt("enter one thing")
things.push (one)


one=prompt("enter one other thing")
things.push (one)

one=prompt("enter one more thing")
things.push (one)

/*
Now we loop through it randomly using Math.random and Math.floor
*/
var toytawl=""
for(var index=0; index<things.length; index++){
var found= Math.floor(Math.random()*things.length)
   toytawl += things[found
things.splice(found, 1)
}
</Script>
</Body>

Translation from Google translate
```

コメントのように、どういうわけか変数への入力を取得する必要があると言われました

簡単にするために、 `window.prompt`を使用し、ランダムな変数を選択するには、各変数を領域に格納し、それを表示するには、document.body.innerHTMLを使用するだけです。

そう

```
<ボディ>

<Body>
var things = []
var one = prompt（ "1つのことを入力してください"）
things.push(one)


one = prompt（ "もう1つ入力してください"）
things.push（one)

one = prompt（ "もう1つ入力してください"）
things.push（one）

/ *
次に、Math.randomとMath.floorを使用してランダムにループします。
* /
var toytawl = ""
for（var index = 0; index <things.length; index ++）{
var found = Math.floor（Math.random（）* things.length）
     toytawl  =things[found]
things.splice（found, 1）
}
document.body.innerHTML = toytawl
</ Script>
</Body>

グーグル翻訳からの翻訳
```